# Using awk to extract specific pattern if it matches otherwise the previous line

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following file:

```
[INFO]   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core ............. 2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
[INFO]   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind ......... 2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
[INFO]   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-avro ...
[INFO]                                                         2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
[INFO]   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor ...
[INFO]                                                         2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
```

What I would like to have at the end is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-avro@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
```

How could I achieve that?

Removing the [INFO] and replacing the ... with @ is quite straightforward, i.e.

```
cat temp1 | sed "s/\[INFO\]//g" | sed "s/\s//g" | sed -E "s/\.\.+/@/"
```

which does:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core@2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind@2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-avro@
2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor@
2.10.4->2.11.0
```

however I'm not sure how I could use awk in order to get all the lines with -> but if the line doesn't have ... then get the previous + the current, otherwise only the current.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NF!=4{tag=$2} NF>3{print tag "@" $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-avro@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor@2.10.4 -> 2.11.0
```

Comment: which example did you use? Because NF is the number of fields and after having removed everything [INFO], ... the NF is always 1

Comment: I need a general solution

Comment: @Symeon If you need a general solution, describe the input properly. This script works fine with your sample

Comment: yes...you're right...It was just for the starting file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to address just the 'next step' after the OP's `cat/sed/sed/sed` step ...

For testing purposes:

```
$ cat com.data
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core@2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind@2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-avro@
2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor@
2.10.4->2.11.0
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN  { pfx="" }                                       # initial printf prefix is empty string

/^com/ { printf "%s%s", pfx, $0 ; pfx="\n" ; next }     # if line starts with "^com" then print prefix and current line
                                                        # set prefix to "\n" for rest of script
                                                        # skip to next line of input

       { printf "%s", $0 }                              # otherwise printf current line

END    { printf "\n" }                                  # print one last "\n" once done
' com.data
```

**NOTE**: Remove comments to declutter code.

The above generates:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core@2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind@2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-avro@2.10.4->2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor@2.10.4->2.11.0
```

OP should be able to implement this with:

```
cat temp1 | sed "s/\[INFO\]//g" | sed "s/\s//g" | sed -E "s/\.\.+/@/" | awk 'BEGIN ... '
```

---

Personally, I'd probably scrap the entire `cat/sed/sed/sed` block in favor of a single `awk` solution (eg, Ed's answer).